# Spotify Web API: Get upcoming tracks

Tags: javascript, spotify

Using the Spotify Web API is possible to:

- Get a list of recently played tracks (`me/player/recently-played`)
- Get the current playing track and context (`me/player`)

Yet it doesn't seem to provide a method to get a list of upcoming/enqueued tracks.

Is there any special context like `spotify:user:me:playlist:upcoming` or similar to get that information?